# Tumblr: Creating a Custom Home Page

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

I have been searching around for links that I thought could help me in designing a customized home page for my tumblr, without showing the posts unless a link refers to a tagged page or a permalink page. Unfortunately I have found nothing that works, at least in the sites I've been to. Could someone please assist me on how to make this work?

Is there a certain code (like Javascript) that I have to insert? I'm pretty vague on Javascript except on CSS3 and HTML. Thanks in advance for answering!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Seperate homepage / tagged / permalink pages

It is possible to have different content / visuals for the following pages:

1. Homepage - http://you.tumblr.com
2. Tagged Page - http://you.tumblr.com/tagged/yourtag
3. Permalink Page - http://you.tumblr.com/post/123456/your-post-title

`{block: IndexPage}`, `{block:PermalinkPage}` and `{block:TagPage}` are your friends.

Below is an example of a homepage with no posts, and the tagged / permalink containing posts.

```
{block:IndexPage}
<h1>Homepage</h1>
<!-- Don't include Post loop here -->
{block:TagPage}
<h1>Tag Page</h1>
<!-- Include Post loop here -->
{block:Posts}
{block:Text} 
{block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}
{Body}
{/block:Text}
{/block:Posts}
{/block:TagPage}
{/block:IndexPage}

{block:PermalinkPage}
<h1>Permalink Page</h1>
<!-- Include Post loop here -->
{block:Posts}
{block:Text} 
{block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}
{Body}
{/block:Text}
{/block:Posts}
{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Inside the `Posts` loop include what ever post types you need. More information can be found here: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#basic_variables & http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tag-pages

Comment: The IndexPage block is displayed on every tagPage (even if the block do not include one another like here). So, it can be helpful to use `<div {block:TagPage}style="display:none"{/block:TagPage}>` to hide some parts of the IndexPage in the TagPage(s).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have three choices:

- Work within tumblr, and do your CSS/JS on there (though I believe it's very limited) through the "Customize" feature (or, you can get a theme that does what you want).
- [Route all of your tumblr posts through a custom domain](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains) name (so your blog shows up as a different domain name instead of yourblog.tumblr.com).
- Make your own custom website, on your own custom webspace, and pull your blogs RSS feed (yourblog.tumblr.com/rss), and then format it however you want.